# How to mount daughter PCBs like HX-2S-JH20

Tags: mount, mounting-holes

How would you mount a PCB like the HX-2S-JH20? It doesn't have any screw holes. What about using plastic supports under the pads and ring terminals. Or maybe is better to solder it on pads on the main PCB as if it were a SMD component?

[image: HX-2S-JH20 board top]

[image: HX-2S-JH20 board bottom]

Comment: A lump of double sided tape?

Comment: @Kartman I thought also to use hot glue, but I prefer a solution that allows for the component removal. Double sided tape seems not robust enough to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably mount it using screw terminals on the main PCB, which you connect it through.

If you don't want to connect it to the main PCB, just leave the terminals unconnected there. Then you can connect a cable with a ring terminal with the same screw.

There are plenty of different models out there, I've used these in the past:
[WE WP-SMBU](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/WP-SMBU_THROUGH-HOLE)
[image: Screw terminals]

Answer (score -2):

These modules are usually designed to be mounted with standard 0.1" pin headers.

Comment: It doesn’t seem right to me: the holes diameter is 3.2 mm, too big for a standard pin header.